# Show product information with mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css, magento-1.7

I have an e-commerce with Magento, and I would like to change the way the information of products are shown, i.e. have a product in the window which shows image, product name and price. I want to show only the image with the name of the product, and the price only when mousing and expand the div but without moving the site structure or if possible, show all the product information on the product, an example is the site of [Netshoes](http://www.netshoes.com.br/).
This is one of the products in the store that I manage: http://liveweave.com/mfBpFK